# sp2013: set datetime column + 3 year in some condition, how?

Tags: content-type, column, date-time, server

I have a **SharePoint 2013** site. I have a **custom document library** with **4 custom content types**. When I upload a document I can select a content type and see 1 DateTime column. I would like to set the DateTime + 3 years. But only for 1 of the 4 content types.

I am a developer, sow every solution is welcome. Also the programmatically (c#, javascript etc.

Comment: You can run a designer workflow on item Added. Check the contenttypeid of the item in workflow and set the datetime column.

Comment: yes, thats a good option where I was also thinking about. But it is nicer when you switch to ct A there is happen nothing, you switch to ct B you see the datetime column filled with datetime of today + 3 year.

Comment: You can also try adding javascript into the EditForm.aspx, which can do that.

Answer (score 1):

A possible non-code solution: Can you add a calculated column for the Date+3 years ONLY to the content type that you want to have  that feature?

Create a new calculated column for that content type and set it using a date formula.

You also could add a datetime column to that content type and set the default value for that column to be date + 3 years, and just tell users not to change it. Not as good of a solution as the calculated column, but still works depending on who is using the document library.

Comment: The date formula solution is very interested. Can I do there some logic to check which contenttype is selected?

Comment: One of the main difference between different content types is the set of columns that are in it, right? So if you only want the date calculation on a specific content type, only add that column to that content type. When you select the content type from the drop down menu, the columns that are specific to that content type will appear in the form, without any checking or coding on your part.

Comment: these 2 date columns are in all contenttypes. But I want to do this logic only at 1 contenttype. Please tell me how?